# How to combine Play JSON objects with parser-combinator JSONObjects?

Tags: arrays, json, scala, playframework, parser-combinators

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import scala.util.parsing.json.{JSON, JSONArray, JSONObject}
```

I have following json array-

```
 val groupNameList = Json.arr(
    Json.obj(
      "groupName" -> "All",
      "maxSeverity" -> allGroupSeverityCount,
      "hostCount" -> (windowsCount + linuxCount + esxCount + networkCount + storageCount + awsLinuxCount + awsWindowsCount)),
    Json.obj(
      "groupName" -> "Private",
      "maxSeverity" -> privateGroupSeverityCount,
      "hostCount" -> (windowsCount + linuxCount + esxCount + networkCount + storageCount)),
    Json.obj(
      "groupName" -> "Public",
      "maxSeverity" -> publicGroupSeverityCount,
      "hostCount" -> (awsLinuxCount + awsWindowsCount))
   )
```

I want to append a following list of json objects to this array -

```
List({"groupName" : "group1", "maxSeverity" : 10, "hostCount" : 1, "members" : ["192.168.20.30", "192.168.20.31", "192.168.20.53", "192.168.20.50"]})
```

I want to merge list into array.

How do I append given list to json array using scala???

Comment: What library is this using?

Comment: @ Martin - I added import statements in my edit. please refer

Comment: In the last snippet where you show the data that you want to append, what is the type of that expression? It looks like an odd combination of Scala and JSON. It is a `List[String]`? `List[JsArray]`?

Comment: It is List[JSONObject]

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to convert JS objects from Scala's parser combinators library to JS objects in Play! The question makes sense now.

Comment: Can you please provide me some help please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (though probably not most efficient) way to convert an object between types of different JSON libraries is via its JSON string representation.

```
(o: JSONObject => Json.parse(o.toString()))
```

Once you have a `List[JsObject]`, you can pass it into the `JsArray` constructor and then use `++` to concatenate the two `JsArray`s.

Putting it together in an example:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, JsArray}
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject

object Foo {

  val jsArray = Json.arr(
    Json.obj("a" -> "b", "c" -> 2),
    Json.obj("d" -> "e", "f" -> 3))

  val list = List(
    JSONObject(Map("g" -> "h", "i" -> 4)),
    JSONObject(Map("j" -> "k", "m" -> 5))
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(jsArray ++ JsArray(list.map(o => Json.parse(o.toString()))))
    // [{"a":"b","c":2},{"d":"e","f":3},{"g":"h","i":4},{"j":"k","m":5}]
  }
}
```